# In Rally js "query" api, can't sort on Blocked

Tags: javascript, sorting, rally

I'm modifying a "Rally" project management software "app".

I added the "Blocked" field to a custom table display.
But when I try to Sort on "Blocked", it doesn't seem to work.

It doesn't error, but it seems to break any ordering following "Blocked".
That is, if I put "Blocked asc/desc" as the first Order column, I have no ordering.  If I put it following one or more other columns, it seems like it sorts on those preceding columns, but not Blocked or anything following.

Here is the relevant section of the api javascript I am modifying:

```
            var queryConfigs = [];
            queryConfigs[0] = { type : 'hierarchicalrequirement',
                key  : 'stories',
                fetch: 'ObjectID,FormattedID,Name,ScheduleState,State,Blocked,' +
                        'Owner,UserName,DisplayName,Tasks,Defects,TestCases,LastVerdict,AttributionKanbanStates',
                query: storyCriteria,
                order: 'Blocked asc, AttributionKanbanStates asc'
            };

. . .
rallyDataSource.findAll(queryConfigs, showResults);
```

Has anyone else had luck sorting by Blocked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [WS API documentation](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/) Blocked is not sortable. Click on HierarchicalRequirement object in the object model, and scroll to Blocked attribute. Sortable is false.

Comment: ah...  thank you.  Sorry for not RTM :)   I appreciate the description of what to look at.  I am still learning that object model.  This is a great example.